# Why this simple makefile does not rebuild the source on changes?

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote this simple makefile, which works fine until I want to do some changes and apply them into binary. Then I need to do 'make clean' and 'make' again, because obj. file will not be rebuilt. Althought it seems like a simple task so far I failed to modify it in order to make obj. file rebuild implicitly (So I can write only 'make' when I modify source).

```
COMPILER=g++-5.3
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -O2 -pedantic

build : a.o
     $(COMPILER) a.o -o a

a.o:
     $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o a.o

clean :
    rm -f *.o *~ a
```

Edit: I tried changes suggested by Omada (I tried the same myself before I wrote this question) and this is result:

```
me@pc: ~/mypath$ cat a.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ( argc!=2 ){
        std::ceaaarr<<"Prrogram expects 1 argument\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}me@pc: ~/mypath$ make
g++-5.3 a.o -o a
me@pc: ~/mypath$ cat Makefile
#init

COMPILER=g++-5.3
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -O2 -pedantic

build: a.o
        $(COMPILER) a.o -o a

a.o: a.cpp
        $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o a.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~ a
```

Comment: `a.o` needs to depend on `a.cpp`.   So change the line `a.o:` to read `a.o: a.cpp`.   Also change the target `build` so it depends on `a`, not `a.o`, and add a target `a: a.o` which does the linking.

Answer (score 5):

Since you never told the makefile that `a.o` depends on `a.cpp`, it won't be able to determine that when `a.cpp` changes, it should rebuild `a.o`.

To fix this change

```
a.o:
    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o a.o
```

to this

```
a.o: a.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) -c a.cpp -o a.o
```

Let me know if it doesn't work, I'm a bit rusty on my makefiles.

Comment: Nope. I made a syntax error in a.cpp and when I wrote 'make' this happens: `g++-5.3 a.o -o a`. This gets more time consuming than it should be :-/. I am using GNU make 3.81 built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu.

Answer (score 1):

If you tell make what to do, it will do what you say.  If you write a rule with a target that builds `a.o` and has no prerequisites listed, then make thinks that the target has no prerequisites: in that case if the target (`a.o`) exists, then make will assume it's up to date.  Omada tells you how to avoid that by adding prerequisites.  You could also, instead of defining your own rule, simply use make's built-in rules that already know how to create an object file from a `.cpp` file (but, it uses the `CXX` variable not `COMPILER`).

Similarly, if you define a rule `build: a.o`, that tells make that in order to build the target named `build`, it should see if a file named `build` exists and if `a.o` is newer than it.  If the file `build` doesn't exist, then it will run the recipe you've provided.

Since your recipe, `$(COMPILER) $(CXXFLAGS) a.o -o a` doesn't actually create a file named `build`, it's always out of date and will always be run.

You must ensure that your recipe actually creates the name of the target you're trying to build:

```
a: a.o
        $(COMPILER) a.o -o a
```